# Hasura filter query - multiple filters of the same name

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, hasura

In react app, I have input's (checkboxes) with different values:

```
-> 0 - 10  
-> 11 - 20  
-> 21 - 30  
-> 31 - 40
```

...etc

I need to send selected values as filter eg. first and 4-th. So it's either one of those two ranges.
My attempt was

```
"where": {  
  _or: [   
    {price: { _lte: 10, _gte: 0 }},   
    {price: { _lte: 40, _gte: 31 } }   
  ]  
 }
```

but this doesn't work.
How to send multiple filters in the same query with the same filter name?

Comment: The example you've shown with the where clause and multiple ranges wrapped inside of `_or` works just fine. What do you mean that it doesn't work? Are you getting back an error or is it just not returning the rows you're expecting?